# Multi select based on another multi select

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I need to filter city based on the country in these multi-selects.
I used `ui-select` for multi-selects, Thanks to @tanmay.

Please take a look at this fiddle.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hasarw/6f7v623g/5/)

Comment: Can you please expand on what your question actually is? Thanks.

Comment: Can you please explain what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Nishant123 As you may see in the Fiddle, I need to filter cities based on their relevant country. It means when I choose the United States only related cities show up. Please take a look at the Fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a function on `ng-change` that will return all the cities for the selected country

```
 $scope.getCityList=function(){

      var sampletemp = []; //temp array to hold filtered values
      $scope.selected.country.forEach(function(country) {
      //bjectFromArrayFilter --> A filter function that will do the filtering
      var temp =    objectFromArrayFilter($scope.samples,'country',country);
      sampletemp = sampletemp.concat(temp);
      //Filter duplicate city names
      $scope.uniquecity = $filter('unique')(sampletemp, 'city');
      //Reset all the already selected values
      $scope.selected.city= [];

      $scope.city = $scope.uniquecity.map(function(item) {
      return item.city
        })
    }
```

The filtering function.

You can also use this function to perform custom filtering. Just pass the array of objects, filtering key and value to match

```
var objectFromArrayFilter=function(arrayOptions, key, value) {
    var filterResult = arrayOptions.filter(function(val) {
            return val[key] === value;
    });
    return filterResult;
};
```

**[FULL EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Kunalh/6f7v623g/10/)**

Similar function can be made for filtering on other `$scope.samples` keys

Comment: I also need to reverse filtering. It means when I chose the city, country option filled. Can you help me about that?

Comment: Filtering both ways might cause errors. Filter either on country OR city