# ui-select: set value from controller

Tags: angularjs, ui-select

I have two ui-select: the first allows to set the category of a food (e.g. meat, vegetable, dessert); the second allows to pick a food from a list of foods.
When inserting a new food, one fills all fields, including category (via ui-select). This is the HTML:

```
<ui-select ng-model="newFood.category" theme="bootstrap">
     <ui-select-match placeholder="Select food category">
           <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
     </ui-select-match>
     <ui-select-choices repeat="category in (foodCategories | filter: $select.search)">
           <span ng-bind="category.name"></span>
     </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

When one wants to edit an existing food, they use the second ui-select to pick the food and I would like the first select to get its category value. This is the HTML:

```
<ui-select ng-model="foodToEditOrRemove.selected" theme="bootstrap" on-select="fillFormFields()">
   <ui-select-match placeholder="Select food to edit or remove">
         <span ng-bind="$select.selected.name"></span>
   </ui-select-match>
   <ui-select-choices repeat="food in (foods | filter: $select.search)">
         <span ng-bind="food.name"></span>
   </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

In my controller, after picking a category from the ui-select, `$scope.newFood` contains the correct values I type in, including category. After picking a food from the other ui-select, fillFormFields is invoked:

```
$scope.fillFormFields = function () {
       $scope.newFood.name = $scope.foodToEditOrRemove.selected.name;
        $scope.newFood.category = $scope.foodToEditOrRemove.selected.category;

    };
```

After this code, newFood has the correct category set and I see the food name in the corresponding input, but the ui-select does not display the value. How can I update the view to bind to the new value?

Comment: Please add a fiddle

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43047205/4331291) might help you to get started